# Why can't I add a new column?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I try to add a new column to my table but MySql gives me this error:

> #1067 - Invalid default value for 'Data'

The code is:

```
ALTER TABLE  `balances` ADD  `Data` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably because `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is *not* a `DATE`, but rather a `TIMESTAMP`.  (however I am not that familiar with MySQL; I work mainly in PostgreSQL)

Comment: Yep, that made it work. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  Since that worked for you, I made my comment an answer so you can mark it as accepted and make it easier for others to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is not a `DATE`, but rather a `TIMESTAMP`.  *(however I am not that familiar with MySQL; I work mainly in PostgreSQL)*

Comment: Since you posted it as answer, delete the comment in order to refrain from duplication.